# add project to solution not applying with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to do basic things with Roslyn but failing really hard. I am stuck trying to add a project to a solution - when I try to add a project to a solution / workspace, it does not apply and the project count remains zero.

Here is my current code. How am I screwing up with something so basic?

```
var workspace = new CustomWorkspace(MefHostServices.DefaultHost);
var project = workspace.CurrentSolution.AddProject("[name]", "__assemblyName__", LanguageNames.CSharp);

workspace.TryApplyChanges(project.Solution); // i have tried it with and without this line

var projectCount = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.Count(); // is still zero
```

Comment: What does TryApplyChanges return?

Comment: It returns `true`, as does `CanApplyChanges`! Which is why I am so confused!

Comment: Does this work now? I mean I can add the project to the solution variable in Debugger in the automatic try apply, but when I let it run it tells me "The addition of projects is not supported".

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug that [we fixed a month and a half ago](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/146532ecfdf1e8657d24965515c0fc1650c3d756), but there hasn't been a new NuGet release with the fix yet. The next update to the packages will contain the fix.